# What is happening to my process?

Tags: python, process

I'm executing a SSH process like so:

```
checkIn()
sshproc = subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True)
exit = os.waitpid(sshproc.pid, 0)[1]
checkOut()
```

Its important that the process form `checkIn()` and `checkOut()` actions before and after these lines of code.  I have a test case that involves that I exit the SSH session by closing the terminal window manually.  Sure enough, my program doesn't operate correctly and `checkOut()` is never called in this case.  Can someone give me a pointer into what I can look in to fix this bug?

Let me know if any other information would helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python process would normally execute in the same window as the `ssh` subprocess, and therefore be terminated just as abruptly when you close that window -- before getting a chance to execute `checkOut`.  To try and ensure that a function gets called at program exit (though for sufficiently-abrupt terminations, depending on your OS, there may be no guarantees), try Python standard library module [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html).

Comment: Very neat module, but didn't solve the problem.  Thank you for the post!

Comment: @gnucom, if you need to ensure some code's execution when your process terminates very abruptly (worst case, via a `kill -9`... or even a HW fault!), you need, by definition, to execute that code in a _separate_ ("daemon") process -- a "watchdog" that does nothing but wait for the main process's untimely exit and, if and when that happens, runs said code.  Being in a different process of course means architectural constrains on what you can and cannot do, but (for sufficiently abrupt terminations) it's the only game in town:-(.

Comment: thank you for the design suggestion.  I think that is what I will end up doing because `kill -9` is essentially the test case that I am stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all you need is a `try ... finally` block?

```
try:
    checkIn()
    sshproc = subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True)
    exit = os.waitpid(sshproc.pid, 0)[1]
finally:
    checkOut()
```

Unless the system crashes, the process receives `SIGKILL`, etc., `checkOut()` should be called.